# your app is using unsafe implementation of hostname verifier

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

When I am uploading my app to playstore it shows the warning

> "your app is using unsafe implementation of hostname verifier"

How to solve this problem.

```
 SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFa‌​ctory());
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

 @Override public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {

       return true; 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Java class name must be mention in there. Please post that as well.

Comment: SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

Comment: this is the code that i had used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Security Alert - Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface here

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { 
    @Override public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) { 
        return true; 
    } 
});
```

Google is pretty strict about it these days.
You can check this [link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426) for more information.

Instead of true always return false whenever the hostname of the server does not meet your expectations.

Instead use

```
@Override
public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) { 
    HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
    return hv.verify("your_domain.com", arg1);
}
```