# How do I solve the problem with my rejected android app in playstore?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

My app is rejected for violating the Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. The HostnameVerifier seems to have a problem and google play send me an email that your app is using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Security Alert - Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fillup google docs for permission.
2. Make sure your permission is given in manifest and give the pop up in user level.
3. Contact google developers as soon as possible.

[See this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)