# Unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface related to PayPal android

Tags: android-security

I never use HostNameVerifier in my application google still sending mail and fix the deadline and I need a suggestion for this question.

I got a alert in google play console find below its related to PayPal I didn't found these classes in my code.

Vulnerable classes:

lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.d$1

lib.android.paypal.com.magnessdk.network.e$1

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: No, i am waiting for solution,  if you find the solution please update - @Mister Fisher

Comment: @MisterFisher have you got the answer

Comment: It fill good... I upgraded to implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.0.0' . To use it, I followed it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113189/braintree-drop-in-ui-error-failed-to-resolve-org-jfrog-cardinalcommerce-gradl

Comment: Thank you @MisterFisher issue is resolved, it means a lot

Comment: my app has been removed from store this morning with the same alert. I don't understand. Do I have to make a new upgrade from the same library ? In this case why I don't have any time limit ? Or, the update doesn't correct the problem. In this cas, I don't what is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the paypal to the latest as per the braintree issue they have resolved the issue from the paypal side. For braintree the latest version is:

```
implementation "com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.15.0"
```

More details available on githug repository:
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/325

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your paypal package to the last version.