# Android app using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-security, android-securityexception

The app is developed in Kotlin and I have used okHttpClient to make API calls
I am trying to host it on play store but they give me a vulnerability issue:

```
HostnameVerifier 
Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how to resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.
```

MY CODE:

```
    private val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
private var httpLogger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

private val customClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(httpLogger)
        .addInterceptor(ConnectivityInterceptor())
        .build()
private val sRetrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(customClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl(DataUtils.getString(R.string.api_base_url))
        .build()
```

The app is running good in debug release though

Comment: Does this help https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426?hl=en, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h

Comment: No this doesn't help

Comment: Hi @VanshTah Do you got a solution for these issues, I'm also facing this issue in my project, if you got a solution please share a solution for these issues, Thank you in advance

Comment: Still struggling

Comment: You should look for an unsecure verifier in one of the libraries that you use. The easiest way I know, is to go trough all suspicious jars in "External Libraries" of your project, and search for HostnameVerifier in each.