# Flutter Android: unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface

Tags: android, flutter, android-security

I got this Mail from the Google Play Support:

> Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier
> interface.

But I can't find the HostnameVerifier interface in my Flutter code. Does anybody know where and how to fix this?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: I found out that the problem was the "flutter_braintree"-package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree). After I removed that, the error disappeared.