# Why insecure hostnameverifier?

Tags: java, android, hostname, android-security

HostnameVerifier

Your app (s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how to solve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

```
okHttpClientBuilder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> {

        Certificate[] certs;
        try {
            certs = session.getPeerCertificates();
            //Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient: "+certs[0] );
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient: "+e.getMessage() );
            return false;
        }
        X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
        // We can be case-insensitive when comparing the host we used to
        // establish the socket to the hostname in the certificate.
        String hostName = hostname.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Verify the first CN provided. Other CNs are ignored. Firefox, wget,
        // curl, and Sun Java work this way.
        String firstCn = getFirstCn(x509);
        System.out.println(TAG + ": firstCn: " + firstCn);
        Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient:1 "+hostName +" "+firstCn );
        if (matches(hostName, firstCn)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient:2 "+hostName+" "+firstCn );
            return true;
        }
        for (String cn : getDNSSubjectAlts(x509)) {
            if (matches(hostName, cn)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient: True" );
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "getHttpClient: False" );
        return false;

    });

    return okHttpClientBuilder.build();


}

private static String getFirstCn(X509Certificate cert) {
    String subjectPrincipal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "getFirstCn: "+subjectPrincipal );
    for (String token : subjectPrincipal.split(",")) {
        int x = token.indexOf("CN=");
        if (x >= 0) {
            return token.substring(x + 3);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See: [Playstore Vulnerablity unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65270287/295004)

Comment: not have a solution in this post..

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231151/295004

Comment: Most likely, this error comes from one of the libraries that you have embedded in your app, not from the cited code.

Comment: thanks, Alex Cohn. It was the main issue which causing this problem. I have fixed it successfully.