# Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface how to solve

Tags: android, android-security

I'm not using any code related to HostnameVerifier but
get mail from Play Console
Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier interface. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

Any one can help?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014233/14759470

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Security Alert - Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h)

Comment: You should look for an unsecure verifier in one of the libraries that you use. The easiest way I know, is to go trough all suspicious jars in "External Libraries" of your project, and search for HostnameVerifier in each.