# Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier

Tags: google-play, android-security

I am facing this issue after uploading apk to the play console. It says:

`Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier`

Play store rejected my app due to this issue, I searched everywhere but didn't find the solution for that so please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: General errors like that are easy to research after , for example look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928435/google-play-security-alert-your-app-is-using-an-unsafe-implementation-of-the-h

Comment: Also in play console in security tab, you see problems with your apk and which class is causing it